# Is Gotham the capital of the United States?

Tags: dc, black-lightning-2018

In *Black Lightning*, Agent Odell, the head of the ASA, lives in Gotham. The commission to examine the truth of the ASA's involvement in Freeland is *also* held in Gotham, not Freeland. Former ASA agent Lady Eve, similarly, was offered the chance to relocate there.

In real life, the head of a federal agency would generally live in or near Washington DC, the capital, and a hearing on a matter of national import involving the federal government would probably also occur there. That said, I feel like someone mentioned Washington D.C. once.

Is Gotham the capital of the US in this series or in other DC works?

Comment: I always read Gotham as equivalent to Chicago, and Metropolis to New York, but I haven't read DC Comics in decades.

Comment: In the real word it meant New York City: see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gotham

Comment: Still, in *this* series it seems as if it might be the capital.

Comment: *"The head of a federal agency would generally live in or near Washington DC"* - citation needed: [Christopher Wray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_of_the_Federal_Bureau_of_Investigation), current [Director of the FBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_of_the_Federal_Bureau_of_Investigation) lives in [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(U.S._state))

Comment: @Chronocidal - He *lived* in Georgia, when his job was there. Does he still? Does he take a two-hour flight to the J. Edgar Hoover building every working day?

Comment: @Adamant - He might be working from home...

Comment: @Valorum - There's not much reason to think he was (before the coronavirus epidemic but after being selected). The Wikipedia article cites two news articles., both of which were published directly after Trump chose him.

Comment: Washington DC does exist as a location in at least some continuities

Comment: @Adamant Many politicians or high-ranking workers (both public and private sector) around the world maintain an apartment or small residence near their official office, but *live* in their home-proper elsewhere.  That way, they need only commute once a week, rather than every day.  Considering Trump's propensity for random hirings-and-firings, it makes sense for Christopher Wray not to completely up-sticks and move to DC.  Or, less controversially, perhaps you'd rather consider the CDC - a Federal Agency which is based in Georgia - or the Railroad Retirement Board, with its HQ in Chicago.

Comment: @Chronocidal - Well, when someone spends the work week in a city, they live there. But aside from that, the implication is that Odell pops off to Gotham for his job, not to spend the weekend with family. The CDC and the Railroad Retirement Board are very unusual cases. The predecessor of the CDC was founded in Atlanta due to the war, and as for the RRB - there is not much more obscure. In any case, while I am sure one could argue that the ASA was founded in Gotham for Reasons, and Freeland is in Gotham's jurisdiction or something thus the hearing, the evidence points in a different direction.

Comment: Many agencies are located elsewhere. For instance, the FAA is in Oklahoma City. Only the Cabinet and their staff actually need to be in DC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Gotham would not be the capital of the US, at least in the post-Crisis Arrowverse which united *Black Lightning*, the original Arrowverse shows, and *Supergirl* on the same world. In *The Flash*, *Arrow*, and *Supergirl* there have been references to Washington as the capital, and on *The Flash*, when they presented a large map showing some locations where things had changed from Earth-1 pre-Crisis (such as the Fortress of Solitude from Earth-38 and Gorilla City from Earth-2 now being present), Washington was *not* indicated as being any different, which one would think would be notable.

As a final nail in the coffin, *Legends of Tomorrow* operated out of the Washington D.C. headquarters of the Time Bureau, aside from travelling there in the past, and Washington is explicitly the capital.

Comment: Have any of those references come *after* the Crisis crossover?

Comment: The map I mentioned on _The Flash_ was specifically meant as a post-Crisis pseudo-guide to some of the changes. Also, in episode 5 of Crisis, Sara calls Ava in Washington and is told the other Legends are still there, except for Mick.

Comment: It is strange, and I would still like to know why Gotham seems to be fulfilling that role for Freeland.

Comment: Perhaps in the post-Crisis Arrowverse, the US operates slightly differently such that things like hearings or inquiries can take place outside of Washington. This isn't that unusual if you look at other countries where things like commissions of inquiry travel around and aren't confined the the capital.